# Ant build file to compile NSIS script

Tags: ant, nsis

I am new to ANT scripting. I need to develop a Ant script to compile .nsi script, which is developed using NSIS 2.46 version.

I am not sure how to start with it.

Can someone suggest how to to do it or post a example Ant script here which does the job of compiling the script which is placed on a local machine drive.

Answer (score 1):

Besides running makensis as an [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task, there exists an [NSIS plugin](http://danielreese.com/nsis-ant/) After downloading this and placing the plugin into the lib folder you can activate it like this:

```
<taskdef name="nsis" classname="net.sf.nsisant.Task">
  <classpath location="nsisant-{version}.jar">
</taskdef>
```

After that is done, you can run the nsis script like this:

```
<nsis script="some_script_path\build_me.nsi">
  <!-- eventually some defines here for controlling the nsis script -->     
</nsis>
```